# Memgraph trigger which only acts upon one relationship

Tags: memgraphdb, memgraph

How can I create a trigger which will automatically create a `distance` property on the `USES` relationship only? The following trigger throws an error during the `CREATE` statement.

```
create trigger setDistance 
ON --> CREATE BEFORE COMMIT EXECUTE
unwind createdEdges as createdEdge
WITH createdEdge
WHERE createdEdge.distance is null and createdEdge:USES
set createdEdge.distance = 0;

create (:Seller)-[:USES]->(:Country);
  ERROR: Trigger 'setDistance' caused the transaction to fail.
  Exception: Only nodes have labels.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `variable:Thing` syntax within a WHERE clause is just for node label filtering, [see documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/querying/clauses/where#13-filter-with-node-labels). You can use the `type` function to get an edge's type as a string, [see documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/querying/functions#scalar-functions).

Hence with how memgraph is currently the trigger should be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER setDistance 
ON --> CREATE BEFORE COMMIT EXECUTE
UNWIND createdEdges AS createdEdge
WITH createdEdge
WHERE createdEdge.distance IS NULL AND type(createdEdge) = "USES"
SET createdEdge.distance = 0;
```